# Visual Studio Code Custom Language IntelliSense and Go to symbol

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of writing an extension for a custom language in Visual Studio Code. Syntax detection is working well via the tmLanguage file. I am trying to figure out how to add intellisense and go to symbol support, neither of which I have been able to find clear documentation on nor reference file(s) to work from.

When I have a file open with my custom language selected and I select go to symbol I get the following error:
Unfortunately we have no symbol information for the file.

Is there any documentation, or can you provide some tips on how to get started, or do we know that these options are not available for custom languages?

Answer (score 4):

@Wosi is correct but he refers the API preview. Since the Nov-release you want to implement a `WorkspaceSymbolProvider` (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceSymbolProvider) to achieve this.

You can find how we did it TypeScript [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript/src/features/workspaceSymbolProvider.ts) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript/src/typescriptMain.ts#L70) is how to register the feature. Basically provide a `provideWorkspaceSymbols` function that given a search string returns a list of symbols.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misinterpreted what the OP wants to achieve with "Go to symbol". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Go to any symbol in workspace**: Implement a `WorkspaceSymbolProvider` and register it in your extension's main.js like this

```
function registerSupports(modeID, host, client) {
    vscode.languages.registerWorkspaceSymbolProvider(new WorkspaceSymbolProvider(client, modeID));
}
```

**Go to symbol (at current cursor position)**: Implement a [`DefinitionProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DefinitionProvider) and register it in your extension's main.js like this

```
function registerSupports(modeID, host, client) {
    vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider(modeID, new DeclarationSupport(client));
}
```

**IntelliSense**: Implement a [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider) and register it in your extension's main.js like this

```
function registerSupports(modeID, host, client) {
    vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(modeID, new SuggestSupport(client), '.');
}
```

See also [HelloWorld extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world) and [Language server example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server).