# Use intellisense of an existing language in a new language extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

The language im trying to write has some parts of html/javascript/css usable in same file, how can i use existing intellisense functions for those languages?

Or somehow tell visual studio that some part of the text is some javascript and not my language?

Comment: Hi Gonzague Defraiteur, did you means you are trying to developer your language extension and meet the intellisense issue of your custom extension? If so, I will help you add the tag 'visual-studio-extensions' to seek for a more professional support.

Comment: I added the tag, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a intellisense extension for your custom language, what you need is a "language service", which is the entity that handles colorizing, intellisense, etc. for a given file extension/type.
For more information, please refer the following video

https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/vsipmarketing/vsx212-adding-a-language-service-into-visual-studio-2010

And following link provide a sample

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage/

You could also refer to the following similar thread:

> IntelliSense: Implement a CompletionItemProvider and register it in
>   your extension's main.js like this function registerSupports(modeID,
>   host, client) {
>       vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(modeID, new SuggestSupport(client), '.'); }

[Visual Studio Code Custom Language IntelliSense and Go to symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640625/visual-studio-code-custom-language-intellisense-and-go-to-symbol)

Comment: well my question is, is it possible to use typescript or css language service from visual studio, in my language service, and how?